# Convert numbers with toString in Ansi C

Tags: c, arrays, char, tostring

Is it possible to use toString operator, or how to convert numbers to char arrays.

Comment: What would toString be?  Something from another language?

Answer (score 4):

```
int myNumber = 27; /* or what have you */
char myBuffer[100];
snprintf(myBuffer, 100, "%d", myNumber);
```

There are several considerations for you to think about here. Who provides the memory to hold the string? How long do you need it for, etc? (Above it's a stack buffer of 100 bytes, which is way bigger than necessary for any integer value being printed.)

Best answer: start using Java. Or Javascript, or C#, or for the love of God almost anything but C. Only tigers lie this way.

Comment: Comparing C with Javascript or C# isn't very useful, IMO.  Each language has its use.  I would rather program in C than in Javascript or C# :-)

Comment: Life is too short to write pure C.

Comment: You should be using `snprintf()` instead of `sprintf()` if it's available.

Comment: OK. Life is still too short. :)

Comment: I'd still use C over JavaScript or C# for most tasks. Maybe Python. But still, C has its uses, and they won't go away soon!

Comment: Surely you mean `myNumber` in the last line, or name your variable `myInt`.

Comment: No autocomplete either on SO! Life still too short. I'm outta here.

Comment: Best luck to write a kernel or driver in Java. Or Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `sprintf()` function.

Comment: You should be using `snprintf()` instead of `sprintf()` if it's available.

Answer (score 2):

`sprintf()` is considered unsafe because it can lead to a buffer overflow. If it's available (and on many platforms it is), you should use `snprintf()` instead.
Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 12345;
    char buf[4];
    sprintf(buf, "%d", i);
}
```

This leads to a buffer overflow. So, you have to over-allocate a buffer to the maximum size (as a string) of an `int`, even if you require fewer characters, since you have the possibility of an overflow. Instead, if you used `snprintf()`, you could specify the number of characters to write, and any more than that number would simply be truncated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 12345;
    char buf[4];
    snprintf(buf, 4, "%d", i);
    //truncates the string to 123
}
```

Note that in either case, you should take care to allocate enough buffer space for any valid output. It's just that `snprintf()` provides you with a safety net in case you haven't considered that one edge case where your buffer would otherwise overflow.

Comment: On some platforms, it's `_snprintf`.

Comment: Why is it safer to truncate than to over-allocate a buffer to the maximum possible size to represent an int? There are many real world cases where truncating would have dire consequences. Printing out a medical prescription, for example.

Comment: Agreed. The example was for illustrative purposes only. However, silent truncation should be preferred to overflowing a buffer as the latter is undefined behaviour and could cause worse than an incorrect result. Care should be taken to allocate enough space in either case.

Comment: If you're truly worried about truncation, check the return value of `snprintf`.  On most platforms it returns the number of bytes that would have been used if the buffer was large enough.  If dynamically allocating memory, you can pass in a zero length and use the return value to `malloc` enough space to hold the formatted string.

Comment: @tomlogic - Why is it safer (or in any way better) to use malloc() rather than to over-allocate a buffer to the maximum possible size needed to represent an int? If the int is volatile the size needed may have changed since the call to snprintf().

Comment: @chrisharris: in the simple case of formatting a single integer, it's easy to allocate a buffer large enough to hold the result.  If you're dealing with other strings of unknown length (for example, a filename), then it's safer to use snprintf to find out how large of a buffer is required.  (Also, good point on the volatile).